# Redhat "httpd" can not start anymore. Showing "suEXEC" and "SELinux" notices

Tags: apache, redhat, rhel, selinux, suexec

I'm on RHEL `6.5` and Apache `2.2.15`. When i now `restart` the HTTPD, i can not start that `httpd` anymore. Showing following things in the `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Fri Aug 01 18:31:48 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:32:35 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Aug 01 18:32:35 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:42:46 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Aug 01 18:42:46 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:43:15 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Aug 01 18:43:15 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:43:59 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:44:12 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:45:03 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

Actually i have already `disabled` the SELinux.
What should i do please?

Answer (score 2):

Check with: `getenforce` if SELinux is really disabled, it has to show: Disabled.

If it's not then change in */etc/selinux/config*: `SELINUX=disabled`, to be sure you can reboot your system but `setenforce 0` should also be working.

When confident that SELinux is disabled then your problem is not related to SELinux. Httpd is telling you in the log that it would be running with the context `unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0`, but since SELinux is disabled there is no way that this is enforced.